# ViewChild show hide form with Id passing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, typescript2.0

I have a parent page with multiple tabs here is the image below.
[image: ViewChild]

Now as i want to **show a form page child page within a parent page** example above location tab is **parent page**, how can i do that, here is a format of my form page below.
[image]

Now if i can cancel **it should hide my form and show the list** as of course i can use `*ngIf` but how can **i show a form page inside this location tab and hide the location list and after cancel clicks it hides the form and shows the list** also i want to pass **Id** as well.

And also i'm using `export const appRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });` inside the **app-routing-module.ts**.

Comment: Can you just share your code using some editor. As this is not clearly explainable.

Comment: @MinalShah as this is a bit complicated to show code .. but in a real sense is what i need is that, i want to show a viewchild page in the place of the location listing when i click cancel in that viewchild page it should revert back to the location listing parent page. And also i want to pass ID in the viewchild page to get data filled form.

Comment: @MinalShah for now i just want to pass the ID via button click and show my form page in the place of location listing.

Comment: Yeah I understood the issue, I have answered the solution below, please check that once.

Comment: @MinalShah i'll try and update you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NgbModal` service.

1. First, [install NgBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).
2. Next, import the modalService in your `ParentComponent`:

   ```
   import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
   ```
3. Add the service to the constuctor.

   ```
   export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
        ...
        constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)
        ...
   }
   ```
4. Finally, in the button click handler, you can call the `open()` method.

   ```
   buttonClicked() {
        ...
        let modalRef;
        modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildComponent);
        ...
   }
   ```

Comment: In the `ChildComponent` make an attribute named `id` like this: `@Input() id: any`. In the `ParentComponent` do this: `modalRef.componentInstance.id = id` right after you open the modal.

Comment: yes i did that and its working thank you but still i can't use cancel in form to return to the parent list page.. ?

Comment: You can use `NgbActiveModal` in the constructor of your `ChildComponent` like this: `constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, public activeModal: NgbActiveModal)`. Remember to import it in the `ChildComponent`: `import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`. Then, you just call the `activeModal.close('message')` method. To read the message in your `ParentComponent`, do this: `modalRef.result.then((result) => { // do something })` after you call the `open()` method.

Comment: Actually i don't have a modal its a div show hide only i just want to hide my div that has a ID on it and show list after cancel.

Comment: I used Output event emitter and it worked for the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in this case,

You should define one other component, containing the input for your form.

lets assume the selector of that component is .
In the component that is used for listing the locations.
Keep all the html code in one div and bind that with the condition ***ngIf** to check whether to show that div or not.

```
<div *ngIf="!selectedId">......</div>
```

In that same component write:

```
<app-location-form [id]="selectedId" (onCancle)="selectedId=undefined"></app-location-form>
```

In this form component take the input to get the selected id and emit the event to close the form and again show the list.
When you click the edit button just set the variable **selectedId** with the id of the row.

Comment: Its works using Input to pass ID in the form ts file and Output to close form in the list page. And with your method above it helped me to show hide.